# Can a ball with radius that is supremum of all radii of open balls that fits in some open set fits in that open set?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Sorry for the awkwardly-worded question. Let $U$ be an open set in metric space $(X,d)$. Fix $x\in U$ and define $R=\sup\{\epsilon>0:\text{$B(x,\epsilon)\subseteq U$}\}$, where $B(x,\epsilon)=\{y\in X:d(x,y)<\epsilon\}$ defines an open ball of radius $\epsilon$.

I am not sure whether it is true that $B(x,R)\subseteq U$. I think the answer is positive and here is my attempt at proof:

Assume to the contrary that $B(x,R)\not\subseteq U$. This means there is some $y\in B(x,R)$ that satisfies $y\notin U$. Then, $y$ satisfies $d(x,y)<R$. Challenge the definition of "sup" to get some $\epsilon^\ast$ s.t. $d(x,y)<\epsilon^\ast<R$ and $B(x,\epsilon^\ast)\subseteq U$. We see that $y\in B(x,\epsilon^\ast)\subseteq U$, which is a contradiction. Hence, $B(x,R)\subseteq U$.

I now have confidence to say that it is indeed the case that $B(x,R)\subseteq U$.

Comment: U sure ? Trivial case, just 1D real numbers, the open set being (-1,1) x being 0 - the supremum R is obviously 1 but the B(0,1) then includes the borders which are not supposed to be in.

Comment: @MBobrik perhaps, I should change the requirement of U. U should be closed?

Comment: Depends of the purpose of definition of R. Do you want to *know* if R defined as above fulfills the stated condition, or do you want to *find* a definition of R fulfilling the condition ?

Comment: @MBobrik I want to know what kind set U that can fit B(x,R). Oddly, my proof shows that B(x,R) can fit in any kind of U...

Answer (score 0):

Your proof works given that you're using "ball" to mean "open ball". If ball includes the boundary, then it isn't true. Is that what you wanted to know?